# I am trying to read LDAP attributes in its primitive type in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read LDAP attributes in its primitive type in java. I am using spring-ldap jar to ready attributes. currently I am getting the result in Object or Attribute class.

Object attributeValue = dirContextAdapter.getObjectAttribute(outputAttribute);

or

Attributes attributes = dirContextAdapter.getAttributes();
Attribute attributeValue = attributes.get(outputAttribute);

But my problem is I need LDAP attribute value in its primitive data type.

I will really appreciate if any one give me code examples

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP attributes are of only two types: string and binary, which in Java corresponds to String and byte[]. Usually String, except for things which have to be binary, like passwords, pictures, certificates, ... So, just cast.

Answer (score 1):

So you already have a SearchResult, from which you get an Attributes object

```
Attributes attrs = searchResult.getAttributes();
```

and you have already found out that you can get an Attribute object from it, by passing the attributes name

```
Attribute attr = attrs.get("myAttrName");
```

Now in LDAP, attributes can have multiple values, so from that Attribute object, you can either get all values as a NamingEnumeration (similar to the Attributes object getAll method, which gives you all Attribute objects as a NamingEnumeration)

```
for (NamingEnumeration values = attr.getAll(); values.hasMore(); ) {
    System.out.println(values.next().toString());
}
```

or you can access the values via index

```
for (int i = 0; i < attr.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(attr.get(i).toString());
}
```

If you are positive that you get only one result, attr.get() will deliver that. To be more precise: attr.get() will give you one of the values, with no guarantee which one. If you don't care about that, you can use this also.

All return values are either String or byte[] Objects.
For further infos, consult the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/naming/directory/Attribute.html).

Answer (score 0):

While my previous response does answer the question you asked, I don't think it is what you meant. I'm guessing you WANT to get "objectSid" attributes from an Active Directory.

objectSid is a binary object and you will find ample code-examples on how to get the usual "S-1-5-..." representation from that byte[] - for example here https://gist.github.com/miromannino/04be6a64ea0b5f4d4254bb321e09d628.
BUT when you request the objectSid via Javas LDAP classes, they convert it to a String, which replaces invalid characters with the unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER U+FFFD (�) - this breaks the objectSid.

To solve this problem, you need to configure the DirContext to leave objectSid in binary form. See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76820099/20012811