# Spring LDAP returns same and incorrect objectSid

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, spring-ldap

In my Spring web application I am unable to retrive the correct `objectId` from currently logged in user with the Active Directory account. All of attributes seems to have the right value, but the `objectId` value is always set to `S-1-5-21-1723711471-3183472479-4012130053-3220159935` and I don't know where it comes from.

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    private ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(LdapConfig.AD_DOMAIN, LdapConfig.AD_SERVER);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new LdapUserDetailsContextMapper());
        return provider;
    }
}
```

**LdapUserDetailsContextMapper**

```
@Slf4j
public class LdapUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {
    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
        log.info("username: " + username); //username is correct
        log.info("DN from ctx: " + ctx.getDn()); // returns correct DN
        byte[] byteSid = ctx.getStringAttribute("objectSid").getBytes();
        String sid = LdapUtils.convertBinarySidToString(byteSid);
        log.info("SID: " + sid); // S-1-5-21-1723711471-3183472479-4012130053-3220159935 everytime

        return new User(username, "notUsed", true, true, true, true,
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails userDetails, DirContextAdapter dirContextAdapter) {

    }
}
```

How to get the correct SID from Active Directory?

Comment: Is it the same for all users?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and it doesn't match to any user I added (I didn't search the whole directory by this SID).

Comment: The last block of characters should be different for different users. If not compare the byte stream of sid of two users and see if it matches. Sid will be unique.

Comment: `ctx.getDn()` is the DN of the user account you want the SID from?

Comment: @GabrielLuci yes :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/ldap/66894-objectsid-and-ldaptemplate

In the second last post, he describes the same issue you're having. In the last post, he describes a fix, which is to add this to the Bean config file:

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="ldap://ldapserver.domain.com:389" />
    <property name="base" value="dc=domain,dc=com" />
    <property name="userDn" value="cn=binduser,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com" />
    <property name="password" value="bindpwd"/>
    <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
        <map>
        <entry key="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary">
            <value>objectSid</value>
        </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You'll have to modify the values for your domain, but I think the important part is the `baseEnvironmentProperties`.

[This thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/ldap/47556-binary-attributes-objectguid-programmatically-set-the-environment) also describes a programmatic way to set that (although, for `objectGuid`, but you can just swap the attribute).

```
AbstractContextSource contextSource = (AbstractContextSource) ldapTemplate.getContextSource();
Map<String,String> baseEnvironmentProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
baseEnvironmentProperties.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectSid");
contextSource.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(baseEnvironmentProperties);
contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Comment: Could you help me how to add this to my `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`?

Comment: If you update your bean config file, you shouldn't need to. If that's not an option, then I'm not really sure. I know AD, but I'm not a Java developer, so I'm a little lost in this myself. That code block doesn't really say where the `ldapTemplate` variable came from. I guess that's the missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by adding the environment properties in the configure method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
}

private ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider =
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(LdapConfig.AD_DOMAIN, LdapConfig.AD_SERVER);

// ************** NEW ENVIRONMENT PROPERTIES **********************************
    Map<String, Object> environmentProperties = new HashMap<>();
    environmentProperties.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectsid");
    provider.setContextEnvironmentProperties(environmentProperties);
// ************** END OF NEW ENVIRONMENT PROPERTIES ***************************

    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new LdapUserDetailsContextMapper());
    return provider;
    }
}
```

And then reading it like this in the UserDetailContextMapper:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsContextMapper.class);

@Override
public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    logger.info(ctx.getDn().toString());
    byte[] byteSid = null;
    try {
        byteSid = (byte[]) ctx.getAttributes().get("objectsid").get();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String sid = LdapUtils.convertBinarySidToString(byteSid);
    logger.info("SID: {}", sid);

    return new User(username, "notUsed", true, true, true, true,
            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));    
}
```

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't about Spring, but vanilla Java LDAP Access (in case someone finds this page looking for that - as I did). When you build your DirContext, you need to tell it to keep objectSid in binary form. Otherwise it will try to decode the bytes into a String, which replaces invalid characters with the unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER U+FFFD (�) - making it impossible to get the correct Sid.

```
DirContext ldapConnect() throws NamingException {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapServer);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapUser);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);

    env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectSid"); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    return new InitialDirContext(env);
}
```

This is basically Gabriel Lucis answer, just for vanilla Java instead of Spring.